# Graph API and friends' info

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm having some problems using Graph API for accessing some friends' info.

I want to be able to retreive information about birthday, location and relationship of my app's user (for whom I obtain the access token) and his friends.

For doing this, in the oauth request for obtain the access token from the user I use these permissions on scope parameter: user_location, friends_location, user_birthday, friends_birthday, user_relationships, friends_relationships

Then, using the access token (ACCESSTOKEN) I obtain in this process I do requests to the Graph API.

If I call "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,username,location,birthday,relationship_status,significant_other&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN" it works fine and the answer contains all the info that I want.

But if I call "https://graph.facebook.com/AFRIENDOFMINE?fields=id,name,username,location,birthday,relationship_status,significant_other&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN" the answer doesn't contain info about birthday, location and relationship, it only contains id, name and username fields.

I understood that permissions "user_XXX" and "friends_XXX" could be used for doing this what I want to do, but I don't know if I am understanding something wrong. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!